# get php date in for loop

Tags: php, date, for-loop

I need to make a for loop that is looping month numbers.
But it should deduct month value in for loop. When month 1 came in it should have go back to 12.

`for($i=0;$i>4;++$i){
echo $month = date('m') - $i;
}`

This shows 0 .

Comment: this loop will not work even once for($i=0;$i>4;++$i)

Comment: How much iterations in `for` loop?

Comment: mistake .. it shold other way round.  for($i=0;$i<4;++$i)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: in this month i need to show last 3 months as 2,1,12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found a solution:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;++$i){  
    $new_month = date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - $i, 1, date("Y")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $start = $month = strtotime('2013-02-01');
    $endmonth = strtotime('2014-01-01');
    while($month < $endmonth)
    {
         echo date('F Y', $month), PHP_EOL;
         echo "<br />";
         $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
    }
?>
```

try this by this loop you can also get month

Answer (score 0):

This would be a pure mathematical way to calculate the desired output:

```
$startMonth = (int)date('m');

for($i=0; $i<30; $i++) {
    $echoMonth = $startMonth - $i;
    if ($echoMonth <= 0 ) {
            echo (12 + ($echoMonth % 12));
    } else {
            echo $echoMonth;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

The %-Operator is the modulo function, which keeps the number you subtract in the range from 0 to 11, this way you can keep your number in the range of 1 to 12.

Hope that's what you are looking for.